# jQuery autocomplete on success need to change value of certain field. Multiple input fields/rows

Tags: jquery

Here is form

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
<table>

<tr>
<input id="zipsearch1" type="text" class="zipsearch if_zipsearch_changed1" />
<input id="account_description1" type="text" disabled />
<input type="text" name="is_zipsearch_changed[]" id="is_zipsearch_changed1" class='is_zipsearch_changed1' size="" style='width:30px;'>
<script>
$(".if_zipsearch_changed1").keydown(function () {
document.getElementById('is_zipsearch_changed1').value = 1;
});
</script>
</tr><br>

<tr>
<input id="zipsearch2" type="text" class="zipsearch if_zipsearch_changed2" />
<input id="account_description2" type="text" disabled />
<input type="text" name="is_zipsearch_changed[]" id="is_zipsearch_changed2" class='is_zipsearch_changed2' size="" style='width:30px;'>
<script>
$(".if_zipsearch_changed2").keyup(function () {
document.getElementById('is_zipsearch_changed2').value = 1;
});
</script>
</tr>
<br>

</table>
</form>
```

And here jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function sendForAutocomplete() {

$('[id^="zipsearch"]').each(function (index, zipsearch) {
var suffix = zipsearch.id.substring(9);
autosave(suffix);
});

function autosave(suffix) {

if ( ($("#is_zipsearch_changed" + suffix).val() > 0) ) {

$('.zipsearch').autocomplete
({
source:"suggest_zip.php?additional_value=" + suffix +"&", minLength: 1,
select: function(event, ui){
ui.item.value=ui.item.account_number;
$("#account_description" + suffix).val(ui.item.account_description);
$("#is_zipsearch_changed" + suffix).val('0');
//alert( ("#is_zipsearch_changed" + suffix) );
}
});

}//if ($("#is_row_changed" + suffix).val() > 0) {

}//function autosave(suffix) {

}//function sendForAutocomplete() {
setInterval(sendForAutocomplete, 400);

});//$(document).ready(function() {
```

1) If to type something in field `zipsearch1` value in `if_zipsearch_changed1` changes to 1

2) if value in `if_zipsearch_changed1` is > 0, then jquery starts to work and sends data to external file; user see options to choose (select)

3) when user selects option value changes to 0 in `$("#is_zipsearch_changed" + suffix).val('0');`

When I type smth in the first row then after success value changes to 0. After the first row, I type something in the second row and select from list, then value in `is_zipsearch_changed2` remains 1.

If at first type in the second row, value `is_zipsearch_changed2` remains 1. But if after the second row I type something in the first row, then value `is_zipsearch_changed1` remains 1, but in `is_zipsearch_changed2` value changes to 0.

Any ideas why such behavior? Main aim is after successful auto complete change value in `is_zipsearch_changedX` to 0

Now thinking may better to use focusout. If user leaves input field, then value in `is_zipsearch_changedX` changes to 0....

Comment: Could you make a fiddle demonstrating this? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: There is external php, it would not work. If instead of external php create internal javascript var with array, then all worked. At the moment I use `$(".if_zipsearch_changed1").focusout(function () {
document.getElementById('is_zipsearch_changed1').value = 0;
});` See no problems. Actually all works also if value remains 1